# Prometheus Docker - Connecting to external machine

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, prometheus

I have two virtual machines, one hosting Prometheus, Grafana, etc `192.15.15.10` and the other hosting an application from a series of Docker containers `192.15.15.20`.

I have configured the Docker daemon.json to contain:

```
{
   "metrics-addr" : "127.0.0.1:9323",
   "experimental" : true
}
```

My `Prometheus.yml` now contains:

```
- job_name: 'docker'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['192.15.15.20:9323']
```

This is attempting to reach the metrics endpoint on the other machine. However, because this config is being executed inside of a docker container, the container doesn't know that IP and cannot reach it (its not on the docker network).

How can I achieve this? Is there a proxy setting or something I could use, or somehow use the docker gateway IP?

Comment: are the VMs able to reach each other?

Comment: @Stefano yes I can curl each vm from the other.

Comment: if you execute `nc -w5 192.15.15.20 9323 | echo $?`, does it return a 0?

Comment: @Stefano yep, no route to host

Comment: if there's no route to host, how could you curl the VMs?

Comment: @Stefano it was my fault, I was curling the wrong port, I think firewall is the issue

Comment: ... and the metric_addr as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your docker is listening only on localhost.

Change the `metrics-addr` to listen on `0.0.0.0:9323`.